# How to install php5-fpm on Debian

Tags: php, debian, apt-get

When I try to install php5-fpm I get the following error:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-fpm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php5-fpm : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: php5-common (= 5.4.39-0+deb7u2) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: ucf but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: tzdata but it is not going to be installed
            PreDepends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve this problem?

My /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian wheezy contrib non-free main
deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/

deb http://ftp.ie.debian.org/debian/ testing main


# Just added following https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/running-fastcgi-php-fpm-on-debian-7-with-apache
deb http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.es.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main contrib non-free
~
```

Comment: What debian version are you using?

Comment: You can try "sudo apt-get update"

Comment: You also can check out this guide getting php-fpm to work on wheezy: https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/apache/running-fastcgi-php-fpm-on-debian-7-with-apache

Comment: @Nidhoegger Debian GNU/Linux 7.8 (wheezy)

Comment: @LachezarTodorov already done several times :-/

Comment: Are you trying to install from official repos or do you have custom lines in your sources.list?

Comment: maybe if you try to install the dependencies manually you will get more accurate error?

Comment: @LachezarTodorov I checked manually the dependencies and they are all installed with correct version...